# How does this function know the variable exists?

Tags: python, networking

I have some code:

```
from scapy.all import *

def sniffFunc(pkt):
    print(pkt.show())
    quit()

myFilter = 'tcp and src host 192.168.1.2 and dst host 52.223.224.41'
sniff(filter=myFilter, prn=sniffFunc)
```

it sniffs a single packet from my host to twitch servers and displays that packet's information. How does sniffFunc() know what the variable 'pkt' is and the value of the variable? I know the name can be whatever the programmer wants with regards to the variable passed to the function, however, once inside, it seems to me that the variable 'pkt' would be empty, yet it contains the wanted value. For example, I would think one would have to do something like:

```
pkt = sniff(filter=myFilter, prn=sniffFunc(pkt))
```

Although this won't work, perhaps it will give some insight into my thought process.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library at all, but the implementation of the `sniff` function will determine how the `prn` function is called. (And this will be documented as well.) Presumably it's called with the argument corresponding to the packet being sniffed.

Comment: You are providing a call-back function. As long as `sniff` knows that it needs to pass the parameter, nothing else is required.

Comment: The help says: _function to apply to each packet. If something is returned, it is displayed._ That's a bit vague (it doesn't even vague about what parameters the callback takes) but by the fact its a function, this is a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions themselves can be saved to variables, then called:

```
f = sniffFunc
f(a_packet)  # Still works
```

The function object called `sniffFunc` is passed to the function like any other object would. Once inside `sniff` ([quite deep inside the code actually](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/bf0725f13ca7a1d9f382a72125b5bca25197171d/scapy/sessions.py#L68)), it takes the function object you gave it and calls it by passing it the packet that it was given:

```
def on_packet_received(self, pkt):
    """DEV: entry point. Will be called by sniff() for each
    received packet (that passes the filters).
    """
    if not pkt:
        return
    if isinstance(pkt, list):
        for p in pkt:
            DefaultSession.on_packet_received(self, p)
        return
    self.__count += 1
    if self.store:
        self.lst.append(pkt)
    if self.prn:
        result = self.prn(pkt)  # Your function was stored in the variable self.prn <<<<<
        if result is not None:
            print(result)
```

`result` is whatever your function returns. You can see that it just prints the return value if there is one.

Comment: Where did you find this documentation? I'm having trouble finding the documentation which may allow better understanding. This is what my understanding is now: sniff() is a function which has several parameters that can or cannot be used (correct terminology?). I don't quite understand how these parameters can be assigned within the sniff() call (e.g. sniff(filter=myFilter) ). I think the code you posted says this: "if prn exists, set result to sniffFunc(pkt)". My understanding of this is very amateur so every bit of information you have will help as I still feel quite confused. Thank you.

Comment: I found this by manually digging through the source and following the data using Pycharm to assist. It can be verified by putting a `breakpoint()` in the function that you give it, and checking the callstack using `bt`. And `sniff` has many optional parameters.  And yes, you can think of `result = self.prn(pkt)` as basically `result = sniffFunc(pkt)` for the purposes of getting a general idea of what's going on here.

Comment: @wiregh0st I added a link to the github source in my question so you can explore it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Really appreciate the help. I'm starting to see what's happening here and this will give me a chance to learn more code! I'm one to ask many questions as I want to know the why and how of every detail. With coding I've been having trouble searching for and finding the detailed answers I'm looking for. On another topic, do you have a good resource for callback functions in Python? I can Google it but looking for a personal opinion. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't know of any resources for understanding callbacks in particular. Using them is the best way to wrap your head around them. Try writing the standard functional [`map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) function that takes a function and a list, and returns a new list where the function was applied to each element in the list. Python has this already: `list(map(timesTwo, [1, 2, 3]))` (where `timesTwo` is a function that takes a number and multiplies it by two) returns `[2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks again!